# Error on SPICE simulation in Tanner

Tags: spice

I am trying to make a simple CMOS NOT gate using Tanner. I have made schematic using S-Edit. On simulation, A error is being thrown.

```
Fatal Error : Missing MOSFET model definition for "NMOS"
Fatal Error : Missing MOSFET model definition for "PMOS"
```

After some research I found that some model is required. I tried `generic_025.lib`. But on simulation a new error is being thrown.

```
Fatal Error : "Generic_025.lib" line 27 Misplaced .ENDL
```

So, first of all I doubt about `.lib` file. I think it should be `.md` file. If it is like that than from where can I download this `.md` file?

If `.lib` file is correct than what is error in that file?

Thank you for your help.

This is code of my NOT Gate.

```
.include "C:/Tanner EDA/Libraries/Generic_025.lib"

*-------- Devices: SPICE.ORDER > 0 --------
MNMOS_1 N_1 N_2 Gnd Gnd NMOS W=2.5u L=250n AS=2.25p PS=6.8u AD=2.25p PD=6.8u  
MPMOS_1 N_1 N_2 Vdd Vdd PMOS W=2.5u L=250n AS=2.25p PS=6.8u AD=2.25p PD=6.8u  
VVoltageSource_1 N_2 Gnd DC 5 

********* Simulation Settings - Analysis section *********
.dc lin VVoltageSource_1 0 5 100m

********* Simulation Settings - Additional SPICE commands *********

.end
```

And [this is the link](https://github.com/dhirajt/common-digital-gates/blob/master/Libraries/Models/Generic_025.lib) for `Generic_025.lib` I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your technology is 0.25um, I see that is true but not true in related place. You have to define this GENERIC_025.ext into L-Edit>>tools>>extruct setup>>extract standart rule set click to activate>>click to pencil on the right>>please browse your extract definition file in order to it accepts that GENERIC_025.ext file. That should be done beforer.

While you are in T-Spice screen, please include **"mosfetdegerleri.txt"** file instead of your ".include "C:/Tanner EDA/Libraries/**Generic_025.lib**""

First, copy all definitions below, paste it to new text file on your desktop, then save it as .txt file

```
.MODEL NMOS NMOS (                                LEVEL   = 49
+VERSION = 3.1            TNOM    = 27             TOX     = 5.8E-9
+XJ      = 1E-7           NCH     = 2.3549E17      VTH0    = 0.3551677
+K1      = 0.4881677      K2      = -1.465714E-6   K3      = 1E-3
+K3B     = 3.2222493      W0      = 1E-7           NLX     = 1.927361E-7
+DVT0W   = 0              DVT1W   = 0              DVT2W   = 0
+DVT0    = 0.5751286      DVT1    = 0.5660833      DVT2    = -0.3026132
+U0      = 305.8066794    UA      = -1.152667E-9   UB      = 2.42808E-18
+UC      = 4.12734E-11    VSAT    = 1.287591E5     A0      = 1.7957675
+AGS     = 0.359392       B0      = 1.272642E-10   B1      = 4.171173E-9
+KETA    = -9.762332E-3   A1      = 4.569146E-4    A2      = 0.531924
+RDSW    = 175            PRWG    = 0.15           PRWB    = -0.1243425
+WR      = 1              WINT    = 0              LINT    = 2.8E-9
+XL      = 0              XW      = -4E-8          DWG     = -1.5E-8
+DWB     = 2.37129E-9     VOFF    = -0.1090174     NFACTOR = 1.5319983
+CIT     = 0              CDSC    = 2.4E-4         CDSCD   = 0
+CDSCB   = 0              ETA0    = 6.182294E-3    ETAB    = 2.692579E-4
+DSUB    = 0.0454551      PCLM    = 1.6205616      PDIBLC1 = 0.9594821
+PDIBLC2 = 2.748496E-3    PDIBLCB = -0.0220856     DROUT   = 1
+PSCBE1  = 6.837438E8     PSCBE2  = 2.319772E-4    PVAG    = 9.53415E-3
+DELTA   = 0.01           RSH     = 3.8            MOBMOD  = 1
+PRT     = 0              UTE     = -1.5           KT1     = -0.11
+KT1L    = 0              KT2     = 0.022          UA1     = 4.31E-9
+UB1     = -7.61E-18      UC1     = -5.6E-11       AT      = 3.3E4
+WL      = 0              WLN     = 1              WW      = 0
+WWN     = 1              WWL     = 0              LL      = 0
+LLN     = 1              LW      = 0              LWN     = 1
+LWL     = 0              CAPMOD  = 2              XPART   = 0.5
+CGDO    = 4.57E-10       CGSO    = 4.57E-10       CGBO    = 1E-12
+CJ      = 1.556442E-3    PB      = 0.99           MJ      = 0.4227041
+CJSW    = 4.217952E-10   PBSW    = 0.9814315      MJSW    = 0.1974203
+CJSWG   = 3.29E-10       PBSWG   = 0.8515942      MJSWG   = 0.2684911
+CF      = 0              PVTH0   = -6.690647E-3   PRDSW   = -8.4
+PK2     = 1.959318E-3    WKETA   = 3.50257E-3     LKETA   = 8.792764E-4     )
*
.MODEL PMOS PMOS (                                LEVEL   = 49
+VERSION = 3.1            TNOM    = 27             TOX     = 5.8E-9
+XJ      = 1E-7           NCH     = 4.1589E17      VTH0    = -0.5478816
+K1      = 0.6458081      K2      = -1.621568E-3   K3      = 0.0963219
+K3B     = 5.9878549      W0      = 1E-6           NLX     = 1.468974E-8
+DVT0W   = 0              DVT1W   = 0              DVT2W   = 0
+DVT0    = 2.726151       DVT1    = 0.7470899      DVT2    = -0.1147141
+U0      = 100            UA      = 8.754904E-10   UB      = 1E-21
+UC      = -1E-10         VSAT    = 1.292519E5     A0      = 0.9039776
+AGS     = 0.0844426      B0      = 1.473225E-6    B1      = 5E-6
+KETA    = 7.2918E-3      A1      = 0.03521        A2      = 0.3
+RDSW    = 839.1660575    PRWG    = 0.2331634      PRWB    = -0.0514751
+WR      = 1              WINT    = 0              LINT    = 3.349079E-8
+XL      = 0              XW      = -4E-8          DWG     = -4.722775E-8
+DWB     = -1.6212E-8     VOFF    = -0.1292636     NFACTOR = 0.9361946
+CIT     = 0              CDSC    = 2.4E-4         CDSCD   = 0
+CDSCB   = 0              ETA0    = 0.243084       ETAB    = -0.0204632
+DSUB    = 0.9978554      PCLM    = 1.3975173      PDIBLC1 = 4.013259E-3
+PDIBLC2 = 5.534487E-6    PDIBLCB = -1E-3          DROUT   = 0.0591126
+PSCBE1  = 5.132455E9     PSCBE2  = 1.189024E-9    PVAG    = 0
+DELTA   = 0.01           RSH     = 2.9            MOBMOD  = 1
+PRT     = 0              UTE     = -1.5           KT1     = -0.11
+KT1L    = 0              KT2     = 0.022          UA1     = 4.31E-9
+UB1     = -7.61E-18      UC1     = -5.6E-11       AT      = 3.3E4
+WL      = 0              WLN     = 1              WW      = 0
+WWN     = 1              WWL     = 0              LL      = 0
+LLN     = 1              LW      = 0              LWN     = 1
+LWL     = 0              CAPMOD  = 2              XPART   = 0.5
+CGDO    = 5.59E-10       CGSO    = 5.59E-10       CGBO    = 1E-12
+CJ      = 1.87036E-3     PB      = 0.9616687      MJ      = 0.4756791
+CJSW    = 3.115985E-10   PBSW    = 0.8            MJSW    = 0.2684522
+CJSWG   = 2.5E-10        PBSWG   = 0.8            MJSWG   = 0.2786992
+CF      = 0              PVTH0   = 6.913576E-3    PRDSW   = 10.4939271
+PK2     = 1.392595E-3    WKETA   = 1.2571E-3      LKETA   = -3.261413E-3    )
*
```

Now, please include this mosfetdegerleri.txt file into your T-Spice codes area right after *-------- Devices: SPICE.ORDER > 0 --------

You will get no error after doing this.

Please delete specialdevices.md file while you are in with T-Spice codes. No need to work with specialdevices.md code line in T-Spice.